# Who should witness a medical records request form?

Tags: contract-law, witnesses

I have almost filled out a medical records request form for a hospital, but the final lines state that I must sign and my signature must be witnessed, along with a line for the "witness" in question. What does this mean?

Do I need someone legally able to do this? I don't understand.

The document says nothing about this, and expects it to be mailed to them (the hospital). Do I need a notary to do this or what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Unless they ask for a specific type of witness then anyone with legal capacity (no children, insane people etc) will do.

Answer (score 0):

In many states, hospital employees are not allowed to witness these documents. But, any other competent adult can do so. It would be best to have someone who has no financial interest in your death do so.

The going rate for serving as witness is one Big Mac. ;)