# Can or will a notary public sign a contract as a witness?

Tags: contract-law, signature

I have a medical records request form and I need someone to sign as a witness. My first thought is that I should have a notary do this.

Is this legal?

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to have a notary public witness and notarize the signature of a witness on a medical request form, *unless* the form states that it requires a notary and a notarized signature of a witness.

It is legal to have anyone acting in a legal capacity (over 18, not legally incapacitated, etc.) sign as a witness. Sometimes this is as simple as someone at the medical office or your next door neighbor.

As an aside, it's legal to have a notary sign as a witness on a medical records request form as a *non-notary*; but why bother to go that route?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary_public

Earlier answer on LSE: [Who should witness a medical records request form?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8313/who-should-witness-a-medical-records-request-form)